# bootstrap 4 offset

Tags: html, bootstrap

нужно сделать шаблон

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 ">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">2</div>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Не могу понять как его сделать при помощи offset
Если делаю так то отступы слева. Как сделать отступ справа у второй колонки?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">


        <div class="col-md-4 offset-2">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-2 ">2</div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Как возможно реализовать на bootstrap4

Comment: Отступ справа не нужен. Совсем не обязательно забивать все 12 колонок сетки. Вы установили длину крайнего правого столца с `col-md-4` и этого достаточно. Внешне оствшие две колонки будут пусты.

Comment: Спасибо !  Просветили !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">


    <div class="col-md-4 offset-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">2</div>


</div>
```

Вот так получилось